# Instantiate an abstract class using another object's method?

Tags: java, abstract-class, instantiation

I've been looking into creating a barcode scanner program, and in my research I came across something I've never seen before, and I'm not sure exactly what it is doing...

Here's a snippet of my program, including the line I don't understand:

```
import javax.comm.*;    

public class InvScan implements SerialPortEventListener {


static CommPortIdentifier portId1;
SerialPort serialPort1;


public InvScan(){
    serialPort1 = (SerialPort) portId1.open("InvScan", 2000); //what does this mean? 
}
```

See the line where I commented "what does this mean?". SerialPort is an abstract class... I know abstract classes can be instantiated using an anonymous class, but I've never seen this before. This line of code came from a tutorial for a program designed to do something related to what I want to do, but the author didn't explain what is going on here very well (or maybe I just didn't understand?). His notes say:

> we are instantiating the SerialPort object by executing portId1’s open() method. Recall portId1 is a ComPortIdentifier object and the open() method comes from ComPortIdentifier.

I've done some research, and I can't even find another example of whatever is going on here (probably because I don't even know what to call it, really).

This isn't even really essential to my program, as I can just redesign it (and not be a script kiddie, haha), but it's really bugging me that I don't know what is going on in that line.

Comment: The variable container type can be abstract, the instantiated type (which is retrieved from the open method call) will still be a concrete type deriving from the abstract base type.

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? It's just a method that returns an object of type SerialPort. Its actual concrete type is a subclass of Serial Port, which could, or not, be an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual object is an instantiation of a non-abstract subclass derived from `SerialPort`.  All this does is provide guarantees that the abstract methods have been fully defined within that instantiated object.  Internally, this would look something like:

```
public class CommPortIdentifier ... {

...

    public CommPort open(java.lang.String appname, int timeout)
            throws PortInUseException {

        CommPort val = new NonAbstractCommPort( ... );

        // Do something here

        return val;
    }

...

}
```

Being an abstract subclass of `CommPort`, the cast to `SerialPort` is a little risky unless there are guarantees the actual return type of the object is a subclass of `SerialPort`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is returned from `portId1.open` is a subtype of `SerialPort`. An abstract class may still have concrete subtypes; what this code does is cast the returned object to a known supertype.

Answer (score 0):

The line `portId1.open("InvScan", 2000)` calls a method that returns some subclass of `SerialPort`. Then it is cast to `SerialPort`. (Abstract classes can have non-abstract subclasses.)